# restart spawn-fcgi

Tags: nginx, spawn-fcgi

how can i restart spawn-fcgi on nginx server?

Answer (score 2):

Run it with option `-P` to store the PID in some temp file. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -P /var/run/fcgi.pid
```

Then you can kill it by this pid:

```
kill -9 `cat /var/run/fcgi.pid`
```

Comment: And make sure that PID file is writable by spawned process (if you're using -u/-g options) or it will be empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This should be what you are looking for, current version [here](https://github.com/szaydel/Rigel-Major/blob/master/shell-scripts/fastcgi-php)

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/fastcgi-php
#
# System-V like init script for fastcgi-php.
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          fastcgi-php
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $syslog
# Should-Start:      nginx
# Should-Stop:       
# X-Start-Before:    
# X-Stop-After:      
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Fast CGI PHP gateway for Nginx WWW server
# Description:       Script used to spawn a number of php5-cgi processes, 
#                    which are accessed by nginx www server
### END INIT INFO

## Importing generic functions for LSB compliance
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

## Define path which should be searched by the script
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Debug variable could be set to 1 or above, for more detailed output
DEBUG="0"
FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH="/usr/bin/php5-cgi"
FCGIPHP_USER="www-data"
FCGIPHP_GROUP="www-data"
FCGIPHP_CHILDREN="6"
FCGIPHP_MAX_REQUEST="1000"
FCGIPHP_SERVER_ADDR="127.0.0.1"
FCGIPHP_SOCKET="/tmp/php-fastcgi.sock"
PIDFILE="/var/run/php5-fastcgi.pid"
SPAWN_FCGI="/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi"
FCGIPHP_ENV="SHELL PATH USER"

# Primary command used to create spawned processes
# based on the variabled defined above
COMMAND_ARGS="${SPAWN_FCGI} -C ${FCGIPHP_CHILDREN} -s ${FCGIPHP_SOCKET} -f ${FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH} -u ${FCGIPHP_USER} -g ${FCGIPHP_GROUP} -P ${PIDFILE}"

export FCGIPHP_MAX_REQUEST
export FCGIPHP_SERVER_ADDR
ALLOWED_ENV="$FCGIPHP_ENV FCGIPHP_MAX_REQUEST FCGIPHP_SERVER_ADDR"
E=""
for i in $ALLOWED_ENV; do
    eval "x=\$$i"
    E="$E $i=$x"
done

start(){
    echo "[INFO] ... STARTING PHP-FCGI ..."
    if [ -f "${PIDFILE}" ]; then
            echo "[WARN] PHP-FCGI is running already. PID file ${PIDFILE} exists."
            RETVAL=1
        elif [ -n "$(pgrep $(basename ${FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH}))" ]; then
            echo "[WARN] PHP-FCGI is running already. PID file is missing!"
        else
            start_daemon ${COMMAND_ARGS}
            RETVAL=$?
    fi

    # echo $COMMAND_ARGS
    # env - $E $COMMAND_ARGS
}

stop(){
    echo "[INFO] ... STOPPING PHP-FCGI ..." 

    if [ -f "${PIDFILE}" ]; then
            killproc -p "${PIDFILE}"
            rm -f "${PIDFILE}"
            rm -f "${FCGIPHP_SOCKET}"
            RETVAL=$?
        elif [ -n "$(pgrep $(basename ${FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH}))" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "[WARN] PHP-FCGI is not running, or" "[WARN] PID file ${PIDFILE} may have been removed."
            ## echo "[INFO] Removing $(basename ${FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH})"
            killall $(basename $FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH)
            rm -f "${FCGIPHP_SOCKET}"
            RETVAL=$?
        else
            echo "PHP-FCGI is not running."
            RETVAL=1
    fi
}

#Main################
case "$1" in
    'start')
            [ "${DEBUG}" -ge 1 ] && set -x
            log_daemon_msg "Starting Service" "fastcgi-php"
            start
            ;;

    'stop')
            [ "${DEBUG}" -ge 1 ] && set -x
            log_daemon_msg "Stopping Service" "fastcgi-php"
            stop
            ;;

    'status')
            status_of_proc -p "${PIDFILE}" "${FCGIPHP_BIN_PATH}" fastcgi-php
            exit $?
            ;;

    reload|force-reload)  
            log_warning_msg "Online reload not supported"  
            ;;

    'restart')
            log_daemon_msg "Restarting Service" "fastcgi-php"
            stop
            sleep 2
            start
            ;;

    *)
            echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart}"
            ;;

esac

exit "${RETVAL:-1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How was the process for spawn-fcgi started, was it by a command line (manually) or using a rc-script. In either case you can kill the process by first finding the PID

Use the *command ps aux | grep spawn-fcgi* to locate the process and the command *kill -9 **PID***

I recommend slashdot's recommendation of using the rc-script to start and end your spawn-fcgi process.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This answer randomly failed on me (I'm not sure why) but I'm leaving this here because it might help someone.

`killall -9 -w php-cgi`

The "-w" waits.  Because if you try to (re)start spawn-fcgi too soon (without a delay) spawn-fcgi always gave me error, something like "...already in use." (I don't remember the exact error, sorry.)  However, "-w" doesn't work 100% of the time if you plan to put this in cron.  After months of random php failures I decided to switch to php-fpm, which has its own unique problems--proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer to do this kind of process management by using supervisor:
http://supervisord.org/

Supervisor will "hang on to your processes": it will restart as necessary, manage the stdout/stderr logging and give you an explicit command for managing the processes without having to mess with PID files etc.